# Google's recalled Black bar ended up here.

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, top-bar

So, Google's designers finally realized that the black tool bar they were using on top of their websites was distracting, clunky, making the page look cluttered ...

Google has moved away from using that high-contrast element in their websites, but now it seems to be this website is passing through the same stylistic mistake.

Let those that can do something about it recover from this faux pas.

**This is not a question, and it doesn't need an answer.**

It is only an idea that it would be good if it reaches the ears of the designers of this website.

Comment: It was also very difficult (at least for me) to find the meta-link.

Comment: It is ugly and it take more clicks look up my recently upvoted answers.

Comment: I navigated here by choosing a post under 'Community Bulletin', as the word meta no longer appears in the top bar. Is there a more direct route?

Comment: StackExchange drop-down.

Comment: @DanMoore: click on help. That drops down contains Meta (if you are not already on Meta). But going back to main? I haven't figure that out yet.

Comment: Some thing take more clicks, some things take less.  Will that affect user behavior here?  Easy things (like looking at my *Achievements*) will be done more often?  And motivate me to strive for more?  Who knows...after two days, I doubt you do.

Comment: @WillieWong, To get to main, StackExchange dropdown, very first entry 'Mathematics'.